# How to set up postfix / dovecot with SSL to send receive emails from iPhone

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I just installed a fresh copy of dovecot on my VPS.  I am also running postfix, and I first went through [this guide](https://sites.google.com/site/jpiszcz/home/howto-iphone-postfix-dovecot-ssl)  I followed everything as explained.  However when I try to send an email from my iPhone I'm getting the following error,

```
postfix/smtpd[5017]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Permission denied
```

The dovecot configuration file, https://ghostbin.com/paste/c9he3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based above tutorial, you forgot to add these two lines

```
user = postfix
group = postfix
```

after these lines

```
client {
  # The client socket is generally safe to export to everyone. Typical use
  # is to export it to your SMTP server so it can do SMTP AUTH lookups
  # using it.
  path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
  # path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
  mode = 0660
```

Two forgotten lines will tell dovecot to *execute*

```
chown postfix:postfix /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
```

With this setting, postfix daemon can connect to dovecot socket on `/var/spool/postfix/private/auth`.

Comment: I made the changes as you described, but I'm still unable to send email :/

Comment: Well I just made the changes described in this post, and now I'm able to send / receive email, but still not able to send / receive from iPhone :/ http://www.iredmail.org/forum/post5332.html#p5332

Comment: What does postfix say in `maillog`?

Comment: @Chris, I see in other post, you finally solved the problem. Did the answer solves your problem? If yes, please mark it *Accepted* so future visitor will know that this solution is working for your case. If not, please post the solution in answer section (or edit the answer above) so future reader know what's solution in your problem.